# Check if class can be instantiated without parameters

Tags: php, reflection, constructor, instantiation

Say I have a function that creates new instances of a given class:

```
function createInstance($class) {
    return new $class();
}

$dateTime = createInstance('DateTime');
```

How can I change the implementation of this method so that it is 'defensive' and doesn't produce an error if the class doesn't exist or cannot be instantiated with a parameterless constructor?

Checking that a class exists is easy:

```
function createInstance($class) {
    classExists($class)
    return new $class();
}

function classExists($class) {
  if (empty($class) || !class_exists($class))
    throw new InvalidArgumentException("\$class argument invalid - no such class '$class'");
}
```

However, how do I check that a class can be instantiated?

```
function createInstance($class) {
    classExists($class)
    if (canCreateInstance($class))
        return new $class();
    else
        throw new InvalidArgumentException("Cannot create instance of $class");
}

function classExists($class) {
  if (empty($class) || !class_exists($class))
    throw new InvalidArgumentException("\$class argument invalid - no such class '$class'");
}

function canCreateInstance($class) {
  // ???
}
```

I've tried using `method_exists($class, '__construct')`, but like this [REPL demonstrates](https://repl.it/@DanStevens/canCreateInstance-function), this is not reliable because of the presence or absence of a `__construct()` method doesn't determine whether a class can be instantiated. So what does determine this?

Answer (score 4):

You should use reflection to get this information, for example:

```
class Foo
{
    public function __construct(string $a, string $b = '')
    {
        // some implementation
    }
}

class Bar
{
    private function __construct()
    {}
}
```

You can use [ReflectionClass](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php) to get all information about the defined class. For example, you can check if it can be instantiable with help [isInstantiable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.isinstantiable.php) method

```
$reflection = new ReflectionClass(Foo::class);
$isInstantiable = $reflection->isInstantiable(); // get true

$reflection = new ReflectionClass(Bar::class);
$isInstantiable = $reflection->isInstantiable(); // get false
```

Also, you can get information about constructor with help [getConstructor](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getconstructor.php) method

```
$reflection = new ReflectionClass(Foo::class);
$constructor = $reflection->getConstructor();
```

After it, your variable will contain [ReflectionMethod](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionmethod.php) object and you can use it to get all necessary information about it. For instance

```
$constructor->getNumberOfParameters(); // return 2
$constructor->getNumberOfRequiredParameters(); // return 1
```

Comment: `ReflectionClass::isInstantiable` method covers most cases, except class that doesn't have a parameterless constructor. Is there a way to check this?

Comment: @DanStevens if a class doesn't have a constructor method will be used the default constructor and an object will be created

Comment: What I mean is, if a class has a constructor that requires one or more parameters, is there a way to detect this?

Answer (score 1):

The only reason a class couldn't be instanciate is if it was `abstract` or it has a private constructor. You can use the [`ReflectionClass::isAbstract`](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/reflectionclass.isabstract.php) function  to check just that. And you can use the function  [`ReflectionMethod::isPrivate`](https://www.php.net/reflectionmethod.isprivate) to check if the constructor is private. ( thanks to [Cid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8398549/cid) and [Maxim Fedorov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10237950/maxim-fedorov) for pointing it out.)

```
function createInstance($class) {
    classExists($class)
    if (canCreateInstance($class))
        return new $class();
    else
        throw new InvalidArgumentException("Cannot create instance of $class");
}

function classExists($class) {
  if (empty($class) || !class_exists($class))
    throw new InvalidArgumentException("\$class argument invalid - no such class '$class'");
}

function canCreateInstance($class) {
  $reflectionClass = new ReflectionClass($class);
  if($reflectionClass->isAbstract() || $reflectionClass->isPrivate('__construct'))
      throw new InvalidArgumentException("\$class argument invalid - cannot instanciate class '$class'");
}
```

Comment: abstract or having a private constructor, like in singleton pattern

Comment: Non-abstract class sometimes can't be instantiated,  for example, if the class has private constuctor

Comment: `ReflectionClass::isPrivate()` doesn't exist. You can use `new ReflectionMethod($class, '__construct')->isPrivate()` but this will raise an error if the class doesn't have a constructor. Check [this fiddle](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/add72f96af582b4c013ce98695fcd89dd68ef96f)

Comment: @Cid you can use `isInstantiable` method to solve all problems

Comment: No, not quite all problems - what about a constructor with parameters?

Answer (score 0):

As Maxim suggested, the `ReflectionClass::isInstantiable` method can be used to prevent most:

```
function canCreateInstance($class) {
  return (new ReflectionClass($class))->isInstantiable();
}
```

However, this doesn't catch instances where the class doesn't have a parameterless constructor. Fortunately, the error that is generated is catchable, so I've made my `createInstance` method as follows:

```
function createInstance($class) {
    classExists($class)
    if (canCreateInstance($class)) {
        try {
            return new $class();
        } catch (Error $er) {
            throw new Exception("Error instantiating $class", $er->getCode() $er);
        }
    } else {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException("\$class argument invalid - Objects of type $class cannot be instantiated");
    }
}
```

However, I'm guess this will only work for PHP 7 or later, since the [`Error`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.error.php) class was added, so question is still open for PHP 5!